# Changes made in editable PHP Grid do not reflect in Oracle database

Tags: php, oracle, phpgrid

I'm working on a PHP Application with an Oracle Database. I have added a PHP Grid to the webpage which is editable using:

```
$dg -> enable_edit("FORM", "CRUD");
```

However any changes that I make and press submit do not reflect back to the oracle database. I have also enabled debug true in the conf.php file of PHP Grid 7.3 as below.

```
define('DEBUG', true);
```

Is there any additional line of code to be added for it to update in case of an Oracle Database? I have a privileges necessary to make updates to the table yet any change made in PHP Grid Form is not reflected back.